# Validating Json during model binding in spring MVC 3.1

Tags: json, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm attempting to bind json to the model with @RequestBody.

We are validating our model using JSR303.

Here is the method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCampaign.do", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView editCampaign(@RequestBody @Valid Campaign campaign, 
            HttpServletRequest request)
```

If a piece of required information is missing a MethodArgumentNotValidException is thrown (as I read in the docs).  I really want to be able to return this information back to the view so I can show the user that they've not filled out a required field.  Once the exception is thrown, it seems as though it's too late.  Obviously, I don't have a bindingresult to inspect.

Am I incorrectly using the framework?  How do I set up this scenario correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First Of all I recommend you to return String instead ModelAndView especially in Spring 3.1.

If you want to catch Exception from `@ResponseBody` annotated method, I recommend you to use the following:

1) Catch the exception with `@ExceptionHandler` annotation:

```
  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
      public String handleMyException(MethodArgumentNotValidException  exception) {
         return "redirect:errorMessage?error="+exception.getMessage());

              }
```

and then Redirect to view annotated with `@ResponseBody` argument

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/errorMessage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @Responsebody
  public String handleMyExceptionOnRedirect(@RequestParamter("error") String error) {
     return error;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks Danny.

I'm not sure I understand the solution.  Will this suffice so that the spring mvc form:error tags will be processed correctly?

Comment: This solution will return you error to client side using AJAX. this is already up to you how to show error to User. Actually form:error tag triggered by form submit, due to the fact that you are using AJAX submit instead of Form submit. I don't believe you can trigger it correct way.